# PHP APC multiple upload does not work

Tags: php, windows-server-2003, wamp, apc

I tried to use PHP APC to upload files on wamp, windows2003. But when 2 or more uploads are working at the same time, only one upload is working.

It seams that I'm not the only one experiencing this error: 
http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=13719

Can anyone tell how can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> [Note that the file upload tracking is
> not threadsafe at this point, so new
> uploads that happen while a previous
> one is still going will disable the
> tracking for the previous.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.rfc1867)

The way I read it, that's pretty much all there is to it.  You can only track one upload at a time.

Comment: Does it means that is the best solution is other extension?

Comment: Probably.  Personally, I wouldn't bother trying to get this working, myself.

Comment: Looks like they haven't removed that message from the docs, so I'd expect nothing's changed.